# How do I pass the user info from the detailpage unto another page?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, detailview

Flutter Firestore - StreamBuilder Users > ListView Users > DetailPage User > Message User

So I have a stream of my Users Collection from Firestore.

On tap it goes to the detailpage (profile) of that user. But now I also want to integrate the possibility to send that user a message. So I need to pass the data from the detailpage to another page. How do I pass the user info from the detailpage unto another page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are you pushing a new page, you pass the data via parameter to the widget, which is pushed, like this:

```dart
Navigator.of(context).push(
   MaterialPageRoute(
       builder: (context) => const NextPage("Passed data"), // We pass here the data
   ),
);
```

Full example:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text("Home")),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          child: const Text("Button"),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).push(
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => const NextPage("Passed data"), // We pass here the data
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class NextPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String data;
  
  const NextPage(this.data);
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text("Home")),
      body: Center(
        child: Text(data)
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

You can run this example under this link: https://dartpad.dev/e0d3b247da70f6080ea5917ce346c5a4

Comment: The detailpage isn't the problem, the problem is on my detailpage (the profile of one user) has a message button, on tap a new message screen should appear with the username of the person I want to send a message to. How can I pass the data from that specific user detailpage, which is fetched from the document snapshot, and pass it to another page..